# How to access the default connection 'xe' in oracle 11g to create a user?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I want to make Java 1.6 - Oracle Express 11g - JDBC(OJDBC6) code to create a user with all privileges. Now, one of the connections i have is "xe" (I see it in SQL Developer). I want to make my java code access "xe" and then create a user under "xe" (inside the "other users" section). How can I do this ? Please help me to do this.

Currently, I do the job manually. I go to xe, put my password and login to xe. Then, I go the "other users" section and create a user there. I want my code to do all this for me.

Thanks.

Comment: You would want to do this from Java code or from backend?

Comment: Its already done, see comments below.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question I guess you would want to create Oracle user from Java, right?

One approach would be to create a database stored procedure with parameters like username, password, tablespace name, grants, privileges etc and call this SP from Java using `CallableStatement` by passing all necessary parameters.

Comment: Can I do it without a stored procedure ? I want everything to be done by Java code and nothing on the database side. Is that possible ?

Comment: @sweetdreams Of course you can do that from Java, however the code will be messy and and may not tidy and neat if you persist on doing user creation from java. May I ask you for the reason why you do not  want to use a SP?

Comment: I wanted to try all ways. Regardless of how messy it might be, I still want to try it.

Comment: I don't think it will be messy at all. Have a look at this post below, the solution is there -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945255/how-do-i-login-to-xe-connection-in-oracle-11g-with-java-code

Comment: @sweetdreams Definitely this is possible from Java, it is upto the person or team management to decide whether to have the full database user creation code to be in java or use a SP. Regards