# How do I login to 'xe' connection in Oracle 11g with java code?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I want to make java code that does only this:

Login to the 'xe' connection in Oracle 11g database. That's all. 
How can do it ?

EDIT:
yes, i was using JDBC, but unable to login to that connection. My url is `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe`, `username  = sys` and `password = 123456` for the xe or sys connection. Then why can't i login to that connection ?

EDIT:

I am very sorry, I forgot to add that I see another error besides the 1st one, i.e.

```
SQLException: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

This is followed by-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: are you familiar with jdbc, if not  i would suggest you to go through its documentation.

Comment: Please refer to the edit added to the question. Can you tell me how to do the login from code ?

Comment: Always get this error -  ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: @sweetdreams Are you getting this error when you try to login from sqlplus, any other client tool or from your java code? if it is from java code, kindly include full error stacktrace from your exception part.

Comment: Can someone please upvote question to atleast 0 votes ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to connect as SYS you have to use `sys as sysdba`

So in your java code try like the following code

```
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:xe";
    String username = "sys as sysdba";
    String password = "123456";
Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Regards

Comment: Works !I thought that since the username for connection 'xe' is sys and password is 123456, setting my username = sys only in java code would work.
Btw, why does "sys as sysdba" work and not just "sys" ?

Comment: Because sys is a privileged user and hence we need to use  `sys as sysdba`. From doc
`To connect to Oracle Database as a privileged user over a nonsecure connection, you must be authenticated by a password file. When using password file authentication, the database uses a password file to keep track of database user names that have been granted the SYSDBA or SYSOPER system privilege. This form of authentication is discussed in "Using Password File Authentication".`

Comment: Shouldn't be there ; after String password = "123456" ?

Comment: @NenadBulatovic Unquestionably yes, it was a typo and corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your answer is a bit too vague.

- If you want to login to databases through Java, use JDBC.
- If you're wanting to automate the logging in of an external program, you've got the wrong language :)
- If you're wanting to verify the database is up, see the first point.

Overall, look to JDBC.  Oracle's documentation of JDBC can be [found here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC).

Comment: For-

1- yes, please refer to the edit in question.
2- why is it wrong ?
3- no. want to create the database/schema/user/other user or whichever uncommon name oracle decided to give it :(

Answer (score 0):

**You should write the following code :**

```
private String driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
private String dbURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
private String dbUserName="sys as sysdba";
private String dbPassword="123456";


try{
Class.forName(driver);
con=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbUserName,dbPassword);
-----//Rest of your Code//-------
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```