# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io error: Invalid number format for port number in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, oracle, jdbc

I am using oracle 11g xe version.So i have established the classpath and went ahead for the program but was facing these errors:

```
Connecting to database...
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Invalid number format for port number
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:478)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:547)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:225)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:29)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:556)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at jdbcdisplay.main(jdbcdisplay.java:24)
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Invalid number format for port number
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveSimple(AddrResolution.java:497)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:394)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:873)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:258)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1577)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:353)
... 7 more
GoodBye!!
```

Now i have not used any IDE's nor is it done in windows.I am trying to connect via linux terminal and all the help that is available is almost for Windows.
The connection string i am using for the program is:

```
String jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE:orcl";
String user="Sourajyoti";
String password="*******";
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl,user,password);
```

The code i am using is as follows:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class jdbcdisplay
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Connection conn=null;

    try
    {
        String driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);

        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        String jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE:orcl";
        String user="Sourajyoti";
        String password="******";

        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl,user,password);
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String sql="SELECT ENAME,SALARY,HIREDATE FROM EMP";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next())
        {
            String name=rs.getString("ENAME");
            double salary=rs.getDouble(2);
            Date date=rs.getDate("HIREDATE");
            System.out.print("Name: "+name);
            System.out.print("Salary: "+salary);
            System.out.println("Hiredate: "+date);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("GoodBye!!");
}
}
```

Comment: What is the connection string you are using?

Comment: There you go..i have added the edit.

Comment: Try removing the `/XE`. That should work assuming that the SID you are connecting to is `orcl`.

Comment: Didn't work.Instead got a ORA-12505 TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.. and more errors

Comment: What is your SID? Have you followed the instructions on setting up a database? It appears that the default sid is xe, so your connection string would be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe`     http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#XEGSG113

Comment: No the above causes a java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid" error and more.The link is for a setting up a developer in Windows not linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I login to 'xe' connection in Oracle 11g with java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945255/how-do-i-login-to-xe-connection-in-oracle-11g-with-java-code)

Comment: Nope got a bevy of more errors

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue while using REST to connect and retrieve data from an Oracle DB.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:Herong/TopSecret@localhost:1521:XE
jdbc:oracle:thin:Herong/TopSecret@:1521:XE
jdbc:oracle:thin:Herong/TopSecret@//localhost:1521/XE
jdbc:oracle:thin:Herong/TopSecret@//:1521/XE
jdbc:oracle:thin:Herong/TopSecret@//localhost/XE
jdbc:oracle:thin:Herong/TopSecret@///XE
```

These are all valid variations on the connection URL, but I eventually had to remove the port altogether.

```
        "type": "jdbc",
        "name": "test",
        "connection": {
            "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
            "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//QAORACLE11G.server.local/DatabaseName",
            "user": "QA_DBUSER",
            "password": "QA_DBPASSWORD"
        },
```

My reference material [Oracle JDBC Connection URL](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/Oracle-JDBC-Driver-Connection-URL.html)

Comment: Good reference material! I mixed the two syntax variants which caused the "Invalid number format for port number" exception. You have to choose one syntax format: `jdbc:oracle:thin:[user/password]@[host][:port]:SID` OR `jdbc:oracle:thin:[user/password]@//[host][:port]/SID`

Answer (score 0):

Ok the difference was my connection string and i changed it to :

```
String jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
String user="Sourajyoti";
String password="******";
```